# AWS Route 53 - Mailgun - Subdomain - intermittent DNS issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, mailgun

i´ve got an error on sending email to our Mailgun-service on some Email-providers.

we have an subdomain with an mx record that routes to mailgun, to receive emails as http-post.

if i send a message to our mail address ...@msg.artwizz.com with icloud or gmx everything works fine.

but some email provider will get an error called *"X-Postfix; Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=msg.artwizz.com type=A: Host not found"* and i cant find an error.

i checked all DNS settings, they are all correct:

[image: DNS-Settings]

May somebody has the same problem and has an solution :D

thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create new MX records for your TLD (artwizz.com) that contain the same values as msg.artwizz.com.

2) Create an A record for artwizz.com and msg.artwizz.com and point it to some valid web server. It is considered strange for a domain name to not have an A record for the apex. This may be triggering SPAM rules.

3) Since you already have SPF and DKIM enabled, setup DMARC. This will sign your emails and most well designed email servers will respect your emails as not being SPAM.